ffmpeg некорректно создает имя созданного файла
Написал вот такой скрипт к ffmpeg.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "%%∼nG_1.mp4"

К примеру входящий видео файл под именем anna.mp4. На выходе я должен получить видео файл anna_1.mp4. Но почему то я получаю файл с именем %тИ╝nG_1.mp4
Не могу понять почему так происходит. И так происходит с любым входящим файлом вне зависимости от начального имени. На выходе всегда одно и тоже название.
Прошу помощи в реализации.
